# How to change the output file name in a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to change the output file name, fOut, in a bat file, but have no luck so far.

I'm developing on Windows 7 and will deploy the code to Windows 2003 server.

The code looks like this:

```
set fName=%1
set fExt=%fName:~-5,-1%

set fOut=%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%
```

Examples of fOut:

```
abcdc2evv_PAD.dat

abcdefgh33ij_3737_PAD.dat
```

How can I change fOut to get the following file names?

A. Adding FMT_ at the beginning of the file name:

```
FMT_abcdc2evv_PAD.dat

FMT_abcdefgh33ij_3737_PAD.dat
```

B. Adding FMT_ at the beginning of the file name and remove _PAD before .dat:

```
FMT_abcdc2evv.dat

FMT_abcdefgh33ij_3737.dat
```

Addendum:
Just one argument is passed to the bat file: path + file name.

```
x.bat "C\test\xxx.dat"
```

In the bat file:

```
@echo ^-input file name = ^%1

set fName=%1
set fExt=%fName:~-5,-1%

set fOut==%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious - it's not clear what the input to this script is.

However adding FMT_ before should just be a case of changing:

```
set fOut=%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%
```

to:

```
set fOut=FMT_%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%
```

or if you want to put the FMT_ version into another variable, then:

```
set bob=FMT_%fOut%
```

As for removing _PAD, can you not just repeat the `SET fOut` line without the `_PAD`? This would seem to be the simplest way to do it. In fact, removing `_PAD` and prefixing `FMT_` would seem to simply be this:

```
set bob=FMT_%1
```

Comment: I tried the code below, but got an error message.
    set fOut=FMT_%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%  "in the ExecuteCommand. errorMessage: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: In my rush, I used an empty file, which the code excludes from processing. After using a file that has one line of data, I found that this code,set fOut=FMT_%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%, works. On the other hand, this code, set fOut=%FMT_%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%, does not work. It creates an empty file entitled fName.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove pad just take it out of your assignment statement
you have:

```
set fOut=%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%
```

you want:

```
set fOut=%fName:~0,-5%fName:~-5%
```

to add FMT_ just add it at the beginning of the file name:

```
set fOut=%FMT_%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5%
```

Comment: I tried the code below, but got an error message. set fOut=%FMT_%fName:~0,-5%_PAD%fName:~-5% " in the ExecuteCommand. errorMessage: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: the line doesn't produce an error for me, I think we need some more of your batch file here to figure out the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see the Addendum section above.

Comment: setting your output file name shouldn't cause this error, the more likely issue is that the input file is incorrect and it can't find the file...thus you receive this error

Comment: Thanks to your observation, I found the problem. See my comment to the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate the filename from the extension, don't mess around counting chars; there is a built-in method (described in `for /?`):

```
echo Filename=%~n1
echo Extension=%~x1
echo resulting file="FMT_%~1"
REM without _PAD, following with _PAD
set filename="FMT_%~n1_PAD%~x1"
```

If there is really need to remove `_PAD` (as Chris already noted, you are explicitely adding it with your code), just replace `_PAD.` with `.` only:

```
set filename=%filename:_PAD.=.%
```